# How do I use iTextSharp (or iText) to crop and copy a page from one PDF to another

Tags: pdf, itext

I've written code to do the following:

1. Take a PDF of a certain page size (e.g., 8.5" x 11")
2. Create a new PDF with a larger page size (e.g., 17" x 11")
3. Impose the original PDF onto the new one (e.g., 2-up such that the resulting new PDF has the original PDF side-by-side)

To do this, I use the `PdfWriter.GetImportedPage` method to get the current page from the original PDF, then use the `PdfContentByte.AddTemplate(page, x, y)` method to place the original page onto the current page of the new PDF.

My new challenge is that I need to crop the original PDF before adding it to the new PDF. For example, imagine I want to crop 2" off of the original PDF before imposing it. The input PDF would still be 8.5" x 11" and the new PDF would still be 17" x 11", but the two "copies" of the original PDF in the new one would have had 2" removed from its top, right, bottom and left sides.

Hopefully these images can make this clearer. Here's what I have now, doing a 2-up imposition. (This is working swimmingly.)

[image: Current 2-up imposition]

But here's what I need to do:

[image: Desired 2-up imposition with 1" crop]

I know that I can alter the *display* of the PDF in a viewer by using the MediaBox or CropBox settings, but those settings aren't respected by `AddTemplate`. I know that with `AddTemplate` I can use a transform matrix to position the page or to scale or rotate it, but I don't want to shrink the original PDF, I want to crop it.

Thanks

Comment: This might not be a template thing, you might need to crop the document you're adding. I played with PDFs, but that project is somewhere in the archives at home. Once I get home, I can look for what I did if no one answers your question by then :)

Comment: As with most SO questions I asked, I (think I) figured it out once I hit Submit. I found some code online that showed setting the `BoundingBox` of the imported page to crop it, which I can do before `AddTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use the `BoundingBox` of the imported page to crop it prior to adding it to the new PDF (via `AddTemplate`).

So my code looks something like this:

```
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pageNumber);

// Crop!
page.BoundingBox = new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);

// Add to new PDF
writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, x, y);
```

That does the trick!